# What is Apple Card and how do I get one?

Tags: apple-card

Apple released Apple Card this month (August 2019). What is it and how is it different from other similar cards?

How do I apply for it? How do I know if it's available in my country?

Comment: This really should have one question and not three. The first alone is covered in many long articles and quite subjective. The second two are fine as stand alone questions unless you want to ask, “where does apple document the onboarding process?” This also is still pre-release so putting dates what you refer to as “recent” will let this age well in 2 weeks, 2 months, 2 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple Card, a self branded card is a new kind of credit card to be used in conjugation with Apple Pay. It is created by Apple in partnership with Goldman Sachs. Apple claims to have focused on simplicity, transparency and privacy with Apple Card.

It is currently available only to the citizens of United States. You need to have an [Apple Pay compatible iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208531), running recent version of iOS to be able to use it.

(**Note**: The official documentation doesn't state what is the minimum version required to use Apple Card (it only mentions recent iOS version), Apple Card was rolled out after iOS 12.4 was released. So it could be safely assumed that your device need to run at least iOS 12.4).

You'll also need to have Two-factor authentication enabled for your Apple ID.

> How do I apply for one?

To apply for it, you need to be signed into iCloud with your Apple ID on your iPhone. Once done, open the Wallet app on your iPhone, tap on the ⨁ button, select Apple Card and tap Continue.

You'll be asked to fill out the requisite information. If your application is approved, a digital version of Apple Card is issued immediately, and is ready to use via Apple Pay.

Apple has added an information video on their official YouTube channel demonstrating the application process:

- [Apple Card — How to apply](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVFUocmDNVM)

For scenarios where Apple Pay is not available, such as brick and mortar stores, you can also request Apple for a physical card. The physical card is made up of titanium and carries your name on the front. It is called Titanium Apple Card.

The physical card will be shipped to your address by Apple. It's a Mastercard and can be used anywhere in the world where Mastercard is accepted.

Apple claims that the physical card is more secure than other credit cards as it doesn't contain a card number, CVV code, expiration date or your signature externally.

To learn more about Apple Card, refer to the following Apple Support documents and official links:

- [Apple Card](https://www.apple.com/apple-card/)
- [How to apply for Apple Card](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209257)
- [How to use Apple Card](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209225)
- [Request and use your titanium Apple Card](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209434)
- [How your Apple Card application is evaluated](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209218)

> How do I know if it's available in my country?

Apple Card is currently only being issued to U.S. citizens. To get notified when it gets introduced in your country, subscribe for the news using this link:

- [Apple Card - Notify Me](https://www.apple.com/apple-card/#section-notify)